# Insert records for each selected record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `Table1` contains a list of records with columns `super_id`, `user_name` and `job_type`

`Table2` contains a 3 columns as well `super_id`, `view` and `time`

Using a select query with criteria on table I would like to create one record per `super_id` in `Table2`

Meaning if the select query was `SELECT super_id FROM Table1 WHERE job_type = “Instructor”`

`RF34323` through `RF34328` would appear would each be inserted once into `Table2` where the `View` column is always `View1` and time is the current date.

How can an Select Insert query like this written?

**The following is an example of the 2 tables:**

[image: Example of Tables]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into table2 (super_id, `view`, `time`)
    select super_id, 'view1', now()
    from table1
    where job_type = 'Instructor';
```

Note that `view` and `time` are very BAD choices for column names, because they are keywords in SQL.

If you want to create `table2`, then use `create table table2 as` instead of `insert`.

Also, you can default the `time` column to the insertion time, if you set up the table properly.

Comment: (although  - and perhaps surprisingly - neither is reserved)

Comment: Why are you selecting a value that you want to insert?..."view1" is a value not a column

Comment: @JonathanMense . . . The question states:  "where the View column is always View1".